# Check if subprocess is still running while reading its output line by line

Tags: python, process, subprocess, stdin

I am starting a `subprocess` in Python and trying to read each line of output. Unfortunately I can't find a good way of testing if my processes is still alive. The standard method seems to be checking `poll()`, but that seems to always return `None`. Here is my code.

```
proc = Popen(sys.argv[1:], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

while True:
    process_line(proc.stdout.readline().decode('utf-8'))

    if not proc.poll():
        break

for line in proc.communicate()[0].splitlines():
    process_line(line.decode('utf-8'))
```

I've also tried using `os.kill(proc.pid, 0)`, which works for non-spawned processes, but it seems that Python keeps a handle on processes it starts so `os.kill(proc.pid, 0)` always returns.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You opened a pipe to the process's stdin. Is it waiting to read data?

Comment: No the process only outputs data. In the future I want to add support for both directions, which is why I have that in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to process subprocess output line by line, try this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1)
while p.poll() is None:
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    ...do something with the line here
```

notice I set the buffer size to 1.

also, `os.kill(proc.pid, 0)` is not needed.  Just call
`.kill()` on the subprocess you spawned.  You can also call `.wait()` to wait for termination instead of immediately killing the process.

Comment: This seems to work. Thanks.

Comment: @KrisHarper: there is *no need* to check whether the process is alive if you want to capture its output line by line.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Hmm so in your Python 3 answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/817630, there is no risk of the process ending while lines are still being sent to stdout? Before I was using this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2716032/817630 to the same question, but I see now that it recommends yours instead.

Comment: @KrisHarper if the process is dead then (obviously) it doesn't produce any output and — as soon as already buffered data is read — the loop ends.